# Pull & display new comments without refreshing the page

Tags: comments, jquery, ajax

I've just managed to implement ajax on comment submission and now members don't have to leave the page when they comment but still have to go one extra mile when they want to see new comments.

I've looked around the web before asking this question and I didnt find any real info about doing this.

Anyone has any ideas or maybe already did it?

Right.. I need something like this :

```
     $numComments = wp_count_comments('comments');
      $numComments = $numComments->publish;

    // Posts per page
    $per_page = 50;

    // Determine total amount of pages
    $total_comments = ceil($numComments / $per_page);

    // Get current page
    $paged      = (get_query_var( 'page' )) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

    // Above your loop
    $ignores = array();

    // If we have sent ignore ID's
    if ( $_GET['ignore] )
   {
       $get_ignores = trim($_GET['ignore'], ',');
       $get_ignores = explode(',', $get_ignores);
   }

   // If we have ignore ID's
    if ( !empty($get_ignores) )
    {
        foreach ($get_ignores AS $k => $v)
        {
            $ignores[] = $v;
        }
    }

    $count = 1;

    $my_args = array(
        'per_page' => '50'
        'paged'  => get_query_var( 'page' ),
        'comment__not_in'   => $ignores,
        'comment_status'    => 'publish'
    );                                  

    $my_query   = new wp_list_comments($my_args);

    if ( $paged <= $total_pages):
        $paged = $paged + 1;


        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ): $my_query->the_post();
            // At the start of the loop populate the used post ID's
            $ignores[] = $comments->ID;
?>
<?php $count++; endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php

    if ( $ignores AND is_array($ignores) )
    {
        // Create a comma separated string of ignore ID's
        foreach ( $ignores AS $k => $v ) {
            $ignore_str .= $v.',';
        }

        // Trim the ignore string of any rogue commas
        $ignore_str = ltrim($ignore_str, ',');
        $ignore_str = rtrim($ignore_str, ',');

        $ignore = site_url('page/'.$paged.'/?ignore='.$ignore_str.'');
    }

?>

 <a href="#" rel="<?php echo $ignore; ?>" id="load-more">Load New Comments</a>

 <?php if ( !$my_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

 <?php endif; ?>

   <script>
  (function($){
  $("#load-more").on('click', function(e)
  {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $("#comments").append("<div id='loading'><p>Loading comments</p></div>");

    $("<div>").load($(this).prop('rel') + ' #posts', function()
    {
        $('#comments').append($(this).find("#comments").html()).fadeIn('slow');
        $("#loading").remove();
    });

    e.preventDefault();

       });
     });
 </script>
```

This is just something Im trying to modify to suit my own needs.

Comment: Lester Chan has a plugin. And this tutorial looks promising: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ajaxify-wordpress-comments/

Comment: The tutorial is not what I need. I already submit comments via ajax.

Comment: There is number of solutions around with live comment refresh (P2 theme, spectacula discussion plugin). If you are interested in custom developing this please include what you have already tried and focus on more specific challenges. Otherwise plugin recommendations are [not in scope](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).